# Why does my exe file work proper in cmd but not on double click?

Tags: c, cmd, exe

When I run my C code for squaring a number in cmd, it works proper but when I double click it, it says "Enter any number" but the exe file closes as soon as I press a key.

Here's my code:

```
int main( ){
  float square ( float ) ;
  float a, b ;
  printf ( "\nEnter any number " ) ;
  scanf ( "%f", &a ) ;
  b = square ( a ) ;
  printf ( "\nSquare of %f is %f", a, b ) ;
  return 0;
}
float square ( float x ){
  float y ;
  y = x * x ;
  return ( y ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you double click the program, it will execute and then close because it's finished. You can add these lines at the end of your main function to wait for a key input before finishing:

```
char ch;
scanf("%c",&ch);
```

So it will become something like this:

```
int main( ){
  float square ( float ) ;
  float a, b ;
  printf ( "\nEnter any number " ) ;
  scanf ( "%f", &a ) ;
  b = square ( a ) ;
  printf ( "\nSquare of %f is %f", a, b ) ;

  // Wait for an input to finish the execution
  char ch;
  scanf("%c",&ch);

  return 0;
}

float square ( float x ){
  float y ;
  y = x * x ;
  return ( y ) ;
}
```

Comment: I knew about getch() but I was using it after return 0; and that's why it wasn't working smh. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you know as to why we have to hold the screen when we use double click and not when we use in cmd?

Comment: getch() will do the job, but before the return. :)
When you run your program through CMD, the console is open and the CMD  application is running. So as your program finishes, it goes back to the CMD application, which is in a loop waiting for input, that what holds the console open.

Comment: Thanks man, now I understand.